# Convert Json from HttpResponseMessage to string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I've got code like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/values/1").Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var Samochod = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Samochod>().Result;
            MessageBox.Show("Car ID: " + Samochod.CarID + ", Car Brand: " + Samochod.Marka);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("False");
        }
    }
```

but I'm receiving error in line

```
var Samochod = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Samochod>().Result;
```

Can I convert a Json object from `HttpResponseMessage` response to a string? I was trying to do:

```
string value = response.ToString();
```

But it's nonsense. I have to know what is in Json file I'm receiving from Web API. After that I will know, how to fix error.

Edit:

The problem is, when I'm putting "localhost:8080/api/values/1" directly into browsers, the output is:

```
{"CarID":1,"Marka":"Daewoo","Model":"Lanos","Kolor":"Zielony"`
```

, but when I'm doing this by Win Form application, I'm receing:

```
\"{\"CarID\":1,\"Marka\":\"Daewoo\",\"Model\":\"Lanos\",\"Kolor\":\"Zielony\"}\"
```

And error: "A first chance exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. And Inner Exception in View detail:

```
{"Error converting value \"{\"CarID\":1,\"Marka\":\"Daewoo\",\"Model\":\"Lanos\",\"Kolor\":\"Zielony\"}\" to type 'WebAPIwinForms.Samochod'. Path '', line 1, position 78."}
```

Comment: If you need to know what is in the response, can't you just go to `http://localhost:8080/api/values/1` in a web browser?

Comment: `Can I convert a Json object from HttpResponseMessage response to a string` What is wrong with `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync`

Comment: Receiving error; but what??

Comment: This answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131067/deserialize-json-to-array-or-list-with-httpclient-readasasync-using-net-4-0-ta

Comment: Samochod is a class contains "public int CarID {get; set;} public string Marka { get; set; } public string Model { get; set; } public string Kolor { get; set; }

Comment: @Shagohad don't post it in comments, update your question.

Comment: @EZI -  Your comment with "response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync" resolved my problem, Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2):

you should use ReadAsStringAsync() method to convert string then deserialize to your object for example :

```
var Samochod = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following line:

```
var Samochod = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Samochod>().Result;
```

Please make sure you have installed Newtonsoft.Json, and then update your code as follows:

```
var Samochod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Samochod>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Alternatively, you can utilize the following line, which is an extension method from the System.Net.Http.Json library:

```
var Samochod = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Samochod>();
```

To enable the above-mentioned line of code to execute, you need to modify your method to be asynchronous, as demonstrated below:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Finally, your code should appear like below:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values/1");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var Samochod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Samochod>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        MessageBox.Show("Car ID: " + Samochod.CarID + ", Car Brand: " + Samochod.Marka);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("False");
    }
}
```