# Accessing contents of HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#

I'd like to print the contents of a HTTPResponseMessage.

```
class Requests
{
    public static async Task SendRequest(int port, string path, KVPairs kvPairs)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_ADDRESS + port);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, path);

            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(kvPairs);

            ProcessResponse(await client.SendAsync(request));
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessResponse (HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

SendRequest works perfectly. But ProcessResponse() prints `` System.Threading.Tasks.Task\`1[System.String] ``

How can I access and print the contents of the response? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to await the task returned by `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, which in turn means you need to make `ProcessResponse` an `async` method, and await on that too. Otherwise, you are printing out the task object itself, which is not what you want.

Notice the 3 changes below (see comments):

```
public static async Task SendRequest(int port, string path, KVPairs kvPairs)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_ADDRESS + port);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, path);

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(kvPairs);

        await ProcessResponse(await client.SendAsync(request)); // added await here
    }
}

public static async Task ProcessResponse (HttpResponseMessage response) // added async Task here
{
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()); // added await here
}
```

Comment: Attempting this raises a compiler error on `await ProcessResposne(await client.SendAsync(request))`. Cannot await void. Changing void to Task fixes issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work for you. [Deserialize JSON to Array or List with HTTPClient .ReadAsAsync using .NET 4.0 Task pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131067/deserialize-json-to-array-or-list-with-httpclient-readasasync-using-net-4-0-ta)

You should use await or wait() to get the response and then process it like this:

```
var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

jsonString.Wait();

model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Job>>(jsonString.Result);
```