# Getting A List From Service Async

Tags: c#, .net, json

While trying to get list from an url, program stops and throw an exception like that

> An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

also

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebAPIDemo.Models.Person]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'Message', line 1, position 11.

I thought its because of using `IEnumerable<MyObject>` in my program but when I use only `MyObject` it goes away from this point but it crush into somewhere else.

I'm stuck now.

Here is my code:

`CONTROLLER.CS`:

```
private IEnumerable<Person> CallPersonListServiceAsync(HttpClient ins, string url)
{
    var content = ins.GetAsync(url).Result.Content;
    var personsList = content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(IEnumerable<Person>)).Result as IEnumerable<Person>;
    return personsList;
}
```

`PERSON.CS`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob { get; set; }
}
```

Is it really happening that because I'm using IEnumerable or something different. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131067/deserialize-json-to-array-or-list-with-httpclient-readasasync-using-net-4-0-ta

Comment: What does the JSON that is returned look like? Also, unrelated, try not to block on async code with `.Result`, especially if you are doing this in asp.net.

Comment: `"I thought its because of using IEnumerable"` - You thought correctly.  The error is telling you that the JSON is an object, not an array.  So you would have to deserialize it to an object, not a collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON to Array or List with HTTPClient .ReadAsAsync using .NET 4.0 Task pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131067/deserialize-json-to-array-or-list-with-httpclient-readasasync-using-net-4-0-ta)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the JSON you're receiving is an object, not a collection.  So you have to deserialize it to an object, not a collection.  Unless the JSON is *very* different from what you expect (that is, not a `Person` at all) then you would simply deserialize it to a `Person`:

```
var result =  content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Person)).Result as Person;
```

Which would of course necessitate changing the return type (and name) of your method:

```
private Person CallPersonServiceAsync(HttpClient ins, string url)
```

Alternatively, instead of changing the method signature you could manufacture a list from that single person and return that:

```
return new List<Person> { result };
```

**Additionally**, the async nature of your code is very broken.  For one thing, you are calling `.Result` explicitly which is *almost always* the wrong approach.  Second, your method's name advertises it as an async method but it's not async at all.

You can correct both of these problems by making use of async and await:

```
private async Task<Person> CallPersonServiceAsync(HttpClient ins, string url)
{
    var content = (await ins.GetAsync(url)).Content;
    var result =  (await content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Person))) as IEnumerable<Person>;
    return result;
}
```