# .Net core Web API who calls other external APIs

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, uipath-api

I'm creating a .Net Core web API which will further call an external API.

**Scenario:**

In .Net Core web API, I want to make a Post request to UiPath Orchestrator API to get authentication token. Following is the link for the Request that I want to make
https://postman.uipath.rocks/#8f3b38d8-57dc-4d79-876d-0d2ff897f61a

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> GetAccessToken()
{
  //Here I want to make a Post request to the API to Authenticate
}
```

And response (Auth token) of this will be sent to another post request to start a process
https://postman.uipath.rocks/#738c3beb-1c19-4257-8474-841a054c4220

```
[HttpPost]
 public Task<IActionResult> StartProcess(string token)
 {
   //Here I want to make a Post request to the other API in which token from the previous call will be 
    sent in header
 }
```

I have to complete it in a day or two and I can't figure out how can I achieve this.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#

Answer (score 4):

If I correctly understand you want to have an endpoint, which will make two `POST` requests to third-party API. The first request will retrieve an *Authorization Token*. The second request will use the *Token* in its Headers to pass an authorization.

To achive this behavior, you should to have **a single endpoint** in your API, instead of **two endpoints** (as in your example above).

Also, I recommend you to have a separate class, which will responsible for communicating with your third-party API (with the `postman.uipath.rocks`).

So, your *single endpoint to call a third-party API* may looks like this:

```cs
public class Controller
{
    // another Controller's code...
    private readonly IPostmanApi postmanApi;

    public Controller(IPostmanApi postmanApi)
    {
        this.postmanApi = postmanApi;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> StartPostmanProcess()
    {
        string token = await postmanApi.GetToken();
        await postmanApi.StartProcess(token);

        return Accepted();
    }

    // another Controller's code...
}
```

Your `IPostmanApi.cs` file may looks like this:

```cs
public interface IPostmanApi
{
    ///<summary>
    /// A method to get Authorization Token from Postman
    ///</summary>
    Task<string> GetToken();

    ///<summary>
    /// A method to get start a process in Postman
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="token">Postman's authorization token</param>
    Task StartProcess(string token);
}
```

Your `PostmanApi.cs` file may looks like this:

```cs
public class PostmanApi
{
    Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://postman.uipath.rocks/#8f3b38d8-57dc-4d79-876d-0d2ff897f61a");

            // Note: this code assumes that the whole response body is a string Token.
            // If the `postman.uipath.rocks` returns an JSON object, which contains a
            // Token inside some field, you may use Newtonsoft.Json library to deserialize
            // it, and then retrieve your Token from corresponding field.
            // See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131067/deserialize-json-to-array-or-list-with-httpclient-readasasync-using-net-4-0-ta
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    Task StartProcess(string token)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Note: this code assumes that the `postman.uipath.rocks` receives
            // a **Bearer** token. If it receives another kind of authentication
            // scheme, you should use it instead of "Bearer".
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization 
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            await client.PostAsync("https://postman.uipath.rocks/#738c3beb-1c19-4257-8474-841a054c4220");
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to register your `IPostmanApi` service within `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // another code...

    services.AddScoped<IPostmanApi, PostmanApi>();
    // another code...
}
```

**Notice:**

1. This code is not thread-safe (because an `HttpClient` is not thread safe). If you want it to be thread-safe, consider to use `IHttpClientFactory`.

Useful links:

- [The ways of consume Rest API in .NET Core app](https://code-maze.com/different-ways-consume-restful-api-csharp/amp/)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0