# Consume API from API .NET CORE

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core

I made some API with ASP.NET Core.
Then one of the API need to access 3rd party API. How can I do that?

Let say, the 3rd party API provide JSON format with 3 parameters (Name, address, phone) on it. The 3rd party API is to insert into table.
My API will send a JSON format to the 3rd party API. How can I consume that from my API?

Below is one of my API code:
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> InsertUpdate(Devloperr model)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await repo.InsertUpdate(model);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                return Ok("Data has been saved");
            }
            return Ok("Data not saved");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { return StatusCode(500, e.Message); }
    }
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<int> InsertUpdate(Devloperr model)
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            var cmd = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT `ID` FROM `Table1` WHERE `ID` =@ID";
            var data = await mySqlConnection.QueryAsync<Devloperr>(cmd.CommandText, param: new { ID = model.ID } );

            if (data.Count() == 1)
            {
               cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE `Table1` SET `ID` = @ID, `NAMA` = @NAMA, `USERNAME` = @USERNAME WHERE `ID`=@ID ;";
                parameters.AddDynamicParams(model);
                var result = await mySqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(cmd.CommandText, parameters, commandType: sql);
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO `Table1`(`ID`,`NAMA`,`USERNAME`) VALUES (@ID, @NAMA, @USERNAME);";
                parameters.AddDynamicParams(model);
                var result = await mySqlConnection.ExecuteAsync(cmd.CommandText, parameters, commandType: sql);
                return result;
               
            }

        }
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You can refer to this doc to make HTTP request with expected data to that 3rd party API:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I  just answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845936/net-core-web-api-who-calls-other-external-apis/66846433#66846433) about this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My API will send a JSON format to the 3rd party API. How can I consume that from my API?

You can register an `IHttpClientFactory` and use it to [configure and create HttpClient instance in your ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0) Web API project, then make HTTP request(s) to that 3rd party API.

*Calling `AddHttpClient` to register `IHttpClientFactory`*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    services.AddHttpClient();

    // ...
    // Remaining code deleted for brevity.
}
```

*Make HTTP request from your API action*

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"bearer {your_token_here}");

var mdata = new { Name = "test", Address = "xxx", Phone = "123456789" };

var content = new StringContent(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(mdata), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


var response = await client.PostAsync("https://xxxX/api/XXX", content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //...
}
```