# How do I read a section in JSON result by httpClient?

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, httpresponse

**Here's the C# code to retrieve the JSON:**

```
try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceConfig.DataGapsBaseUrl);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/piper/jobs/" + jobId.ToString() + "/status");

            var token = await GetToken();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var info = JObject.Parse(result);
            return true;
        }
```

**How do extract this specific section (highlighted in yellow) in JSON returned?** Dfid is the unique id for this record.

[image]

```
    {
    "outputs": {},
    "execution": [
        {
            "jobId": "8871d0ca0f324aae9685f768b00eddfb",
            "createTime": "2023-04-02T21:49:34.913+0000",
            "name": "dependency tasks",
            "startTime": "2023-04-02T21:49:34.934+0000",
            "id": "ae3d668f2bef4e5ca9ae262159b271ad",
            "label": "dependency tasks",
            "taskNumber": 1,
            "type": "dependency",
            "priority": 0,
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "dfId": "ad2bb0db-402a-47f6-928d-3fe4276ee417",
                    "name": "df_TCparamtest_alternateid_value_mapping_not_type_DOBAl_175234",
                    "type": "runDataFlow",
                    "label": "Data",
                    "userId": 17,
                    "livyServer": 101,
                    "parameters": "{\"limit_rows\":\"limit 2000\",\"Run_Id\":\"\",\"Batch_Id\":\"4229223\"}",
                    "stopOnTaskFailure": "N",
                    "stopDependentTasks": "N"
                }
            ],
            "status": "COMPLETED"
        },
        {
            "stopOnTaskFailure": "N",
            "label": "Data",
            "stopDependentTasks": "N",
            "type": "runDataFlow",
            "priority": 0,
            "userId": 17,
            "parentId": "ae3d668f2bef4e5ca9ae262159b271ad",
            "output": "{\"status\":\"Completed\",\"message\":[{\"name\":\"Transform_out\",\"status\":\"Completed\",\"message\":\"Transform_out executed successfully and processed 0 rows\"},{\"name\":\"Data_compare_unformattednumber\",\"status\":\"Completed\",\"message\":\"Data_compare_unformattednumber executed successfully. The Details are :  Duplicates In A : 0  Duplicates In B : 0  Only In A : 0  Only In B : 0  Difference : 0  Matched : 0 \"},{\"name\":\"startComponent\",\"status\":\"Completed\",\"message\":\"Component executed successfully\"},{\"name\":\"Transform_in\",\"status\":\"Completed\",\"message\":\"Transform_in executed successfully and processed 0 rows\"}],\"runId\":2863}",
            "executionTime": 87765,
            "jobId": "8871d0ca0f324aae9685f768b00eddfb",
            "livyServer": 101,
            "dfId": "ad2bb0db-402a-47f6-928d-3fe4276ee417",
            "createTime": "2023-04-02T21:49:34.924+0000",
            "name": "df_TCparamtest_alternateid_value_mapping_not_type_DOBAl_175234",
            "progress": 100,
            "startTime": "2023-04-02T21:49:34.927+0000",
            "id": "f38cf10e30a54c1694d32413a7d53689",
            "endTime": "2023-04-02T21:51:02.693+0000",
            "parameters": "{\"limit_rows\":\"limit 2000\",\"Run_Id\":\"\",\"Batch_Id\":\"4229223\"}",
            "status": "COMPLETED"
        }
 {
            "stopOnTaskFailure": "N",
            "label": "Data",
            "stopDependentTasks": "N",
            "type": "runDataFlow",
            "priority": 0,
            "userId": 11,
            "parentId": "47fd48802c2040849911dcef5f63aaa9",
            "output": "{status=Error, message=[GDP5007025 : Unable to run dataFlow in cluster/pipelineError details : GDP40407000: Unable to get or create the Livy sesssion]}",
            "executionTime": 10247,
            "jobId": "e6bef25e8aab48b59e550bf4b3317773",
            "livyServer": 101,
            "dfId": "346fc5a1-86f5-4642-aceb-49c3c161a206",
            "createTime": "2023-04-04T19:40:30.635+0000",
            "name": "df_TCparamtest_alternateid_value_mapping_DOBal_672375",
            "progress": 100,
            "startTime": "2023-04-04T19:40:30.639+0000",
            "id": "09801f3dc2f1448b9bdb6bcf109476f6",
            "endTime": "2023-04-04T19:40:40.886+0000",
            "parameters": "{\"limit_rows\":\"limit 1000\",\"Batch_Id\":\"null\"}",
            "status": "ERROR"
        }
    ],
    "inputs": {
        "Batch_Id": 4229223
    },
    "currentTask": -1,
    "label": "Pipeline",
    "priority": 0,
    "pipelineId": "5b51b5ba2af142c4b10a68db35f2dd18",
    "createTime": "2023-04-02T21:49:34.892+0000",
    "webhooks": [],
    "startTime": "2023-04-02T21:49:34.900+0000",
    "id": "8871d0ca0f324aae9685f768b00eddfb",
    "endTime": "2023-04-02T21:51:02.717+0000",
    "status": "COMPLETED"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON to Array or List with HTTPClient .ReadAsAsync using .NET 4.0 Task pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131067/deserialize-json-to-array-or-list-with-httpclient-readasasync-using-net-4-0-ta)

Comment: You have to post a json string as text not an image if you want to get some help

Comment: Just posted the JSON String

Comment: @Chaka Thanks, and what the data do you want . All that is in yellow and what is the problem? What is the difference between the data above yellow?

Comment: Everything if possible. I need the yellow at minimum. Thank you for the complete code. Will review tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deserialize data in yellow, you have to fix  "output" and "parameters" properies since they  still remains a json string after parsing

```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(result)["execution"][1];
    jObj["output"]=JObject.Parse( (string)jObj["output"]);
    jObj["parameters"]=JObject.Parse( (string)jObj["parameters"]);

    string dfid =  (string) jObj["dfId"];   // ad2bb0db-402a-47f6-928d-3fe4276ee417
    string outputStatus = (string) jObj["output"]["status"]; // Completed
```

or you can deserialize it to a C# class instance

```
    Execution execution = jObj.ToObject<Execution>();
    outputStatus = execution.output.status; // Completed

public class Execution
{
    public string stopOnTaskFailure { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string stopDependentTasks { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string parentId { get; set; }
    public Output output { get; set; }
    public int executionTime { get; set; }
    public string jobId { get; set; }
    public int livyServer { get; set; }
    public string dfId { get; set; }
    public DateTime createTime { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int progress { get; set; }
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
    public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public string limit_rows { get; set; }
    public string Run_Id { get; set; }
    public string Batch_Id { get; set; }
}

public class Output
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Message> message { get; set; }
    public int runId { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i'm using .NET 6, .toObject isn't available for the JObject class?

Comment: In your code I can see  JObject.Parse(result);  It means that you are using Newtonsoft.Json.  And it means that JObject.ToObject<>() is available. Just don't forget to use () at the end.

Comment: @Chaka Pls use my code. I don't have JObject jo = new JObject();  this code doesn't make any sense. I have jObj.ToObject<Execution>(); where jObj is from the previous code.

Comment: Ignore my last message, it worked great! I just misread it.

Comment: Serge - you are the man! I can't thank you enough. You make StackOverflow great!

Comment: Serge, for this line of code: var jObj = JObject.Parse(result)["execution"][1]; it's pointing to  the data in yellow =  the 2nd row in execution.

Comment: What if there are one or many DFIDs (data in yellow)?

Comment: Updated the xml snippet to reflect that. See DFIDs ("346fc5a1-86f5-4642-aceb-49c3c161a206" and  "ad2bb0db-402a-47f6-928d-3fe4276ee417")

Comment: @Chaka Would be the same , you just need to change  var jObj = JObject.Parse(result)["execution"][2]; if you want to reach an added item

Comment: The json is dynamic, it could be 2 or more DFIDs? Is there a way to make it dynamic if I have a count?

Comment: You have an invalid json in the  item you added.

Comment: @Chaka You have changed your question significanly. What are you asking if out of the scope of the stackoverflow. You can post another question with the real json now that has invalid jsons and different  structured items but I am not sure that somebody will spend a month trying to help you.

Comment: Your right, I did add scope. Let me post another thread.