# GET all products by using id field

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have an `WEB API` which have `CRUD` operation. For testing I have created a `Console application`. Create and GET all details are working fine. Now i want to get the product by using `id` field. Below is my code

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
static void ShowProduct(Product product)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {product.Name}\tPrice: {product.Price}\tCategory: {product.Category}", "\n");
    }
static async Task<Product> GetProductAsyncById(string path, string id)
    {
        Product product = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path,id);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
        }
        return product;
    }
case 3:

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Product ID: ");
                    id = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    // Get the product by id
                    var pr = await GetProductAsyncById("api/product/", id);
                    ShowProduct(pr);

                    break;
```

At `client.GetAsync(path,id)` the id is giving me error `cannot convert string to system.net.http.httpcompletionoption`. For this I have checked all the articles related to it. But still unable to find the correct solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I have found couple of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520762/system-net-http-httpcontent-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-readasasync-an). Please try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because there is no method `GetAsync()` that accepts second argument as `string`.

Also, doing `GET` request you should pass `id` in url, i.e. if your api url is something like this: `http://domain:port/api/Products`, then your request url should be `http://domain:port/api/Products/id` where `id` is the id of product you want to get.

Change you call to `GetAsync()` by:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path + "/" +id);
```

or if C# 6 or higher:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path + $"/{id}");
```

Comment: That what i was missing.